# Visual Studio Code Status Bar Source Control Removed

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

I wanted to remove the push-pull changes button from the status bar in vs code, since I usually push to a different branch than I'm currently on when making pull requests (I pull from master though, and frequently commit to it locally).
I right clicked it, and clicked "remove source control". It removed that, as well as the display of the current branch I am on, which I rely on frequently. I have been trying to get it back, but haven't found any way to do so.

While trying to fix it and bring the branch name back, I found the Enable Status Bar Sync setting in the Git extension, which does exactly what I wanted to do originally. However, none of the scm shows up in the status bar any more at all, so the setting doesn't do anything.

Besides documentation:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol

I also tried restarting vs code multiple times, have searched through settings, and haven't found anything close. I uninstalled and reinstalled my various git related extensions as well.

If there is something I can modify in the settings json, I know you can change colors with this:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "statusBar.background" : "#1A1A1A",
    "statusBar.noFolderBackground" : "#212121",
    "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#263238"
}
```

I've also checked all my modified settings in vs code through @modified, and I cannot find something that will make it return.

Any help to get it back is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rick-click the status bar to show and hide different elements